# How to type hint a generic numeric type in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, types, type-hinting

Forgive me if this question has been asked before but I could not find any related answer.

Consider a function that takes a numerical type as input parameter:

```
def foo(a):
    return ((a+1)*2)**4;
```

This works with integers, floats and complex numbers.

Is there a basic type so that I can do a type hinting (of a real existing type/base class), such as:

```
def foo(a: numeric):
    return ((a+1)*2)**4;
```

Furthermore I need to use this in a collection type parameter, such as:

```
from typing import Collection;
def foo(_in: Collection[numeric]):
    return ((_in[0]+_in[1])*2)**4;
```

Answer (score 73, accepted):

[PEP 3141](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3141/) added abstract base classes for numbers, so you could use:

```
from numbers import Number

def foo(a: Number) -> Number:
    ...
```

Comment: just be careful, because `Number` includes `Complex`: `isinstance(0+1j, Number)` is `True`

Comment: right, read it too hastily, but just like me many more will, so I will leave this caveat here

Comment: When I call `foo(1)`, mypy complains `foo has incompatible type "int"; expected "Number"`. In other words: this answer doesn't work for mypy users. See also this open [mypy issue](https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/3186).

Comment: The same is the case for `foo(np.int32(1))`, by the way. mypy raises a similar error: `Argument 1 to "foo" has incompatible type "floating[_32Bit]"; expected "Number"`. Any suggestions what mypy users should do?

Comment: Don't be fooled by the mypy-issue being closed - it was closed by explaining the problems with `Number`: https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/3186#issuecomment-1571512649

Answer (score 27):

There isn't a generic numeric type in the `typing` module, so you would have to create such a type with `Union` instead:

```
from typing import Union

numeric = Union[int, float, complex]

...
```

To add support for Numpy's collection of numeric types, add `np.number` to that Union.

```
numeric = Union[int, float, complex, np.number]
```

**EDIT:** Since all possible numbers are complex numbers, you can also use the protocol `typing.SupportsComplex` instead to type hint any number:

```
from typing import SupportsComplex

def foo(a: SupportsComplex) -> SupportsComplex:
    ...
```

Comment: Note that this won't work for numpy dtypes, but the accepted answer does.

Comment: @sturgemeister I'm a bit confused, because `foo(np.float32(42))` will cause mypy (the static type checker I'm using) to issue `Argument 1 to "foo" has incompatible type "floating[_32Bit]"; expected "Number"`. With what type checker did you verify your statement?

Comment: Suggestion: use `numeric = Union[int, float, complex, np.number]`, this will also work numpy dtypes.

Comment: @normanius with base python, `isinstance(4, Number) and isinstance(np.ones((1,))[0], Number)` returns true, but this seems to be a high priority mypy issue, seems it's difficult to resolve https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/3186

Comment: @sturgemeister Thanks! That issue came to my attention as well. Note that type constructs from the typing module cannot be used for dynamic type checking. Something like `isinstance(4.2, numeric)` will cause a TypeError.

Answer (score 6):

The currently accepted solution of using `Number` is fairly broken considering that, as pointed out in the comments, `int`s are not `Number`s for static type checkers like mypy and PyRight. The situation [has been discussed for years with no clear resolution](https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/3186).

Another possible approach extracted from a [detailed explanation from a related question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69383462) is:

```py
from typing import SupportsFloat as Numeric
```

which has the following behavior:

```py
from decimal import Decimal
from fractions import Fraction
from typing import SupportsFloat as Numeric

import numpy as np


def f(x: Numeric) -> None:
    pass


# Accepted by mypy/Pyright:
f(123)
f(np.uintc(55))
f(Fraction(-3, 2))
f(Decimal("-3.14"))
f(np.array([1, 2, 3]))  # Should an array be numeric?

# Results in type errors:
f(complex(2, 3))
f("asdf")
```

This has the advantage of being fairly permissive, except for `complex`. In case you want to include `complex` as well, simply do

```py
from typing import SupportsFloat, Union

Numeric = Union[SupportsFloat, complex]
```

or equivalently in Python ≥3.10 style:

```py
from typing import SupportsFloat, TypeAlias

Numeric: TypeAlias = SupportsFloat | complex
```

It's perhaps unfortunate that NumPy arrays are considered numeric in the sense of `SupportsFloat`, but that illustrates the obscure philosophical nature of the question "what is a number?".

### Major disadvantage:

As noted by @lkwbr, the `SupportsFloat` type is only really suitable for identifying numbers. It fails to support any operators like addition or comparison.

For instance, Pyright gives the following error:

> Operator "<" not supported for types "SupportsFloat" and "SupportsFloat"

Comment: This generates Pylance linting errors for comparison operators. @blhsing's answer functions better in this regard.

Comment: Thanks @lkwbr, you're absolutely correct, and I've updated my answer accordingly.