# How to hint at number *types* (i.e. subclasses of Number) - not numbers themselves?

Tags: python, type-hinting, python-typing

Assuming I want to write a function that accepts any type of number in Python, I can annotate it as follows:

```py
from numbers import Number

def foo(bar: Number):
    print(bar)
```

Taking this concept one step further, I am writing functions which accept number types, i.e. `int`, `float` or `numpy` dtypes, as arguments. Currently, I am writing:

```py
from typing import Type

def foo(bar: Type):
    assert issubclass(bar, Number)
    print(bar)
```

I thought I could substitute `Type` with something like `NumberType` (similar to `NotImplementedType` and friends, [re-introduced in Python 3.10](https://bugs.python.org/issue41810)), because all number types are subclasses of `Number`:

```py
from numbers import Number
import numpy as np

assert issubclass(int, Number)
assert issubclass(np.uint8, Number)
```

As it turns out (or at least as far as I can tell), there is no such thing as a generic `NumberType` in Python (3.9):

```py
>>> type(Number)
abc.ABCMeta
```

Is there a clean way (i.e. without runtime checks) to achieve the desired kind of annotation?

Comment: Do you know all of the subclasses that the number might be? You might use `Union[int, float, double]` if you only have those three.

Comment: @rajah9 I do not make to make any assumptions about what subclasses I can expect. In fact, I want to be as flexible as possible.

Comment: `Number` *is* the generic (abstract) number type. I would expect `type[Number]` to accept `int`, `float`, etc as arguments.

Comment: (But see https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/3186; it's a long thread, and it's not clear what solution, if any, is suggested.)

Comment: I'm not quite following what is expected by the question or the bounty. A ``Number`` is an abstract concept; there is no concrete feature of a ``Type[Number]`` other than that it can be instantiated to get a ``Number``. Even that is still somewhat hand-wavy, since a ``Type`` is not necessarily meaningful to instantiate. So what are the features this "``Type[Number]``" must imply?

Answer (score 59, accepted):

### In general, how do we hint *classes*, rather than *instances of classes*?

In general, if we want to tell a type-checker that any *instance* of a certain class (or any *instance of a subclass* of that class) should be accepted as an argument to a function, we do it like so:

```
def accepts_int_instances(x: int) -> None:
    pass


class IntSubclass(int):
    pass


accepts_int_instances(42) # passes MyPy (an instance of `int`)
accepts_int_instances(IntSubclass(666)) # passes MyPy (an instance of a subclass of `int`)
accepts_int_instances(3.14) # fails MyPy (an instance of `float` — `float` is not a subclass of `int`)
```

> *[Try it on MyPy playground here!](https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=latest&python=3.10&gist=a841287b8f05dcc6aa3ef679c65febd0&flags=show-error-codes%2Cstrict)*

If, on the other hand, we have a class `C`, and we want to hint that the class `C` *itself* (or a subclass of `C`) should be passed as an argument to a function, we use `type[C]` rather than `C`. (In Python <= 3.8, you will need to use `typing.Type` instead of the builtin `type` function, but as of Python 3.9 and [PEP 585](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0585/), we can parameterise `type` directly.)

```
def accepts_int_and_subclasses(x: type[int]) -> None:
    pass


class IntSubclass(int):
    pass


accepts_int_and_subclasses(int) # passes MyPy 
accepts_int_and_subclasses(float) # fails Mypy (not a subclass of `int`)
accepts_int_and_subclasses(IntSubclass) # passes MyPy
```

> - *[Try it on MyPy playground here!](https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=latest&python=3.10&gist=7a3e1a9fe35b3431d7978e7cc11b3a85&flags=show-error-codes%2Cstrict)*
> - *Read [the MyPy docs on "the type of class objects".](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/kinds_of_types.html#the-type-of-class-objects)*
> - *See also: [Subclass in type hinting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46092104/subclass-in-type-hinting)*.

---

**How can we annotate a function to say that *any* numeric class should be accepted for a certain parameter?**

`int`, `float`, and all the `numpy` numeric types are all subclasses of `numbers.Number`, so we should be able to just use `type[Number]` if we want to say that all numeric classes are permitted!

At least, Python *says* that `float` and `int` are subclasses of `Number`:

```
>>> from numbers import Number 
>>> issubclass(int, Number)
True
>>> issubclass(float, Number)
True
```

And if we're using a *runtime* type-checking library such as [typeguard](https://pypi.org/project/typeguard/), using `type[Number]` seems to work fine:

```
>>> from typeguard import typechecked
>>> from fractions import Fraction
>>> from decimal import Decimal
>>> import numpy as np
>>>
>>> @typechecked
... def foo(bar: type[Number]) -> None:
...     pass
... 
>>> foo(str)
Traceback (most recent call last):
TypeError: argument "bar" must be a subclass of numbers.Number; got str instead
>>> foo(int)
>>> foo(float)
>>> foo(complex)
>>> foo(Decimal)
>>> foo(Fraction)
>>> foo(np.int64)
>>> foo(np.float32)
>>> foo(np.ulonglong)
>>> # etc.
```

But wait! If we try using `type[Number]` with a *static* type-checker, it doesn't seem to work. If we run the following snippet through MyPy, it raises an error for each class except for `fractions.Fraction`:

```
from numbers import Number
from fractions import Fraction
from decimal import Decimal


NumberType = type[Number]


def foo(bar: NumberType) -> None:
    pass


foo(float)  # fails 
foo(int)  # fails 
foo(Fraction)  # succeeds!
foo(Decimal)  # fails
```

> *[Try it on MyPy playground here!](https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=latest&python=3.10&gist=b21b1372081db2d3362f305e7bc5c364&flags=show-error-codes%2Cstrict)*

Surely Python wouldn't lie to us about `float` and `int` being subclasses of `Number`. What's going on?

---

### Why `type[Number]` doesn't work as a static type hint for numeric classes

While `issubclass(float, Number)` and `issubclass(int, Number)` both evaluate to `True`, neither `float` nor `int` is, in fact, a "strict" subclass of `numbers.Number`. `numbers.Number` is an Abstract Base Class, and [`int`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/b34dd58fee707b8044beaf878962a6fa12b304dc/Lib/numbers.py#L393) and [`float`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/b34dd58fee707b8044beaf878962a6fa12b304dc/Lib/numbers.py#L264) are both registered as "virtual subclasses" of `Number`. This causes Python *at runtime* to recognise `float` and `int` as "subclasses" of `Number`, even though `Number` is not in the method resolution order of either of them.

> *See [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2010692/what-does-mro-do) for an explanation of what a class's "method resolution order", or "mro", is.*

```
>>> # All classes have `object` in their mro
>>> class Foo: pass
>>> Foo.__mro__
(<class '__main__.Foo'>, <class 'object'>)
>>>
>>> # Subclasses of a class have that class in their mro
>>> class IntSubclass(int): pass
>>> IntSubclass.__mro__
(<class '__main__.IntSubclass'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'object'>)
>>> issubclass(IntSubclass, int)
True
>>>
>>> # But `Number` is not in the mro of `int`...
>>> int.__mro__
(<class 'int'>, <class 'object'>)
>>> # ...Yet `int` still pretends to be a subclass of `Number`!
>>> from numbers import Number 
>>> issubclass(int, Number)
True
>>> #?!?!!??
```

> What's an Abstract Base Class? Why is `numbers.Number` an Abstract Base
> Class? What's "virtual subclassing"?
>
> - *[The docs for Abstract Base Classes ("ABCs") are here.](https://docs.python.org/3/library/abc.html)*
> - *[PEP 3119, introducing Abstract Base Classes, is here.](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3119/)*
> - *[The docs for the `numbers` module are here.](https://docs.python.org/3/library/numbers.html#module-numbers)*
> - *[PEP 3141, which introduced `numbers.Number`, is here.](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3141/)*
> - *I can recommend [this talk by Raymond Hettinger, which has a detailed explanation of ABCs and the purposes of virtual subclassing.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S_ipdVNSFlo)*

The issue is that [MyPy does not understand the "virtual subclassing" mechanism that ABCs use](https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/1459#issuecomment-216059366) (and, [perhaps never will](https://github.com/python/typeshed/issues/3576#issuecomment-672899447)).

MyPy does understand *some* ABCs in the standard library. For instance, [MyPy knows that `list` is a subtype of `collections.abc.MutableSequence`](https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=latest&python=3.10&gist=1b7dabd701d6c3db13b5d6489ad13c08&flags=show-error-codes%2Cstrict), even though `MutableSequence` is an ABC, and [`list` is only a virtual subclass of `MutableSequence`.](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/2f205920127bd93eebed044cb1b61834764478ba/Lib/_collections_abc.py#L1162) However, MyPy *only* understands `list` to be a subtype of `MutableSequence` *because we've been lying to MyPy* about the method resolution order for `list`.

MyPy, along with all other major type-checkers, uses the stubs found in the [typeshed repository](https://github.com/python/typeshed) for its static analysis of the classes and modules found in the standard library. If you look at [the stub for `list` in typeshed](https://github.com/python/typeshed/blob/32bc2161a107db20c2ebc85aad31c29730db3e38/stdlib/builtins.pyi#L746), you'll see that `list` is given as being a direct subclass of `collections.abc.MutableSequence`. That's not true at all — [`MutableSequence` is written in pure Python,](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/9626ac8b7421aa5fc04a30359521d24f40105141/Lib/_collections_abc.py#L1047) whereas [`list` is an optimised data structure written in C](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Objects/listobject.c). But for static analysis, it's useful for MyPy to *think* that this is true. Other collections classes in the standard library (for example, [`tuple`](https://github.com/python/typeshed/blob/32bc2161a107db20c2ebc85aad31c29730db3e38/stdlib/builtins.pyi#L714), [`set`](https://github.com/python/typeshed/blob/32bc2161a107db20c2ebc85aad31c29730db3e38/stdlib/builtins.pyi#L854), and [`dict`](https://github.com/python/typeshed/blob/32bc2161a107db20c2ebc85aad31c29730db3e38/stdlib/builtins.pyi#L806)) are special-cased by typeshed in much the same way, but numeric types such as [`int`](https://github.com/python/typeshed/blob/32bc2161a107db20c2ebc85aad31c29730db3e38/stdlib/builtins.pyi#L175) and [`float`](https://github.com/python/typeshed/blob/32bc2161a107db20c2ebc85aad31c29730db3e38/stdlib/builtins.pyi#L250) are not.

**If we lie to MyPy about collections classes, why don't we also lie to MyPy about numeric classes?**

A lot of people (including me!) think we should, and discussions have been ongoing for a long time about whether this change should be made (e.g. [typeshed proposal](https://github.com/python/typeshed/pull/3108), [MyPy issue](https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/3186)). However, there are various complications to doing so.

> *Credit goes to [@chepner](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1126841/chepner) in the [comments for finding the link to the MyPy issue.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69334475/how-to-hint-at-number-types-i-e-subclasses-of-number-not-numbers-themselv/69383462#comment122628224_69334475)*

---

### Possible solution: use duck-typing

One possible (albeit slightly *icky*) solution here might be to use `typing.SupportsFloat`.

`SupportsFloat` is a runtime-checkable protocol that has a single `abstractmethod`, `__float__`. This means that any classes that have a `__float__` method are recognised — both at runtime *and by static type-checkers* — as being subtypes of `SupportsFloat`, even if `SupportsFloat` is not in the class's method resolution order.

> What's a protocol? What's duck-typing? How do protocols do what they do? Why are some protocols, but not all protocols, checkable at runtime?
>
> - *[PEP 544, introducing `typing.Protocol` and structural-typing/duck-typing](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0544/), explains in detail how `typing.Protocol` works. It also explains how static type-checkers are able to recognise classes such as `float` and `int` as subtypes of `SupportsFloat`, even though `SupportsFloat` does not appear in the method resolution order for `int` or `float`.*
> - *[The Python docs for structural subtyping are here.](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#nominal-vs-structural-subtyping)*
> - *[The Python docs for `typing.Protocol` are here.](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Protocol)*
> - *[The MyPy docs for `typing.Protocol` are here.](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/protocols.html)*
> - *[The Python docs for `typing.SupportsFloat` are here.](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#protocols)*
> - *[The source code for `typing.SupportsFloat` is here.](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/d441437ee71ae174c008c23308b749b91020ba77/Lib/typing.py#L2163)*
> - *By default, protocols cannot be checked at runtime with `isinstance` and `issubclass`. [`SupportsFloat` *is* checkable at runtime because it is decorated with the `@runtime_checkable` decorator](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/d441437ee71ae174c008c23308b749b91020ba77/Lib/typing.py#L2162). Read [the documentation for that decorator here.](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.runtime_checkable)*

*Note: although user-defined protocols are only available in Python >= 3.8, `SupportsFloat` has been in the `typing` module since the module's addition to the standard library in Python 3.5.*

---

**Advantages of this solution**

1. Comprehensive support* for all major numeric types: `fractions.Fraction`, `decimal.Decimal`, `int`, `float`, `np.int32`, `np.int16`, `np.int8`, `np.int64`, `np.int0`, `np.float16`, `np.float32`, `np.float64`, `np.float128`, `np.intc`, `np.uintc`, `np.int_`, `np.uint`, `np.longlong`, `np.ulonglong`, `np.half`, `np.single`, `np.double`, `np.longdouble`, `np.csingle`, `np.cdouble`, and `np.clongdouble` all have a `__float__` method.
2. If we annotate a function argument as being of `type[SupportsFloat]`, [MyPy correctly accepts* the types that conform to the protocol, and correctly rejects the types that do not conform to the protocol.](https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=latest&python=3.10&gist=5f9378d479cefcf7f422a48108b4406c&flags=show-error-codes%2Cstrict)
3. It is a *fairly* general solution — you do not need to explicitly enumerate all possible types that you wish to accept.
4. Works with both static type-checkers and runtime type-checking libraries such as `typeguard`.

**Disadvantages of this solution**

1. It feels like (and is) a hack. Having a `__float__` method isn't anybody's reasonable idea of what defines a "number" in the abstract.
2. Mypy does not recognise `complex` as a subtype of `SupportsFloat`. `complex` does, in fact, have a `__float__` method in Python <= 3.9. However, it does not have a `__float__` method in the [typeshed stub for `complex`.](https://github.com/python/typeshed/blob/fe4062af5491bcd85b1098a2092b615226b1f4a0/stdlib/builtins.pyi#L304) Since MyPy (along with all other major type-checkers) uses typeshed stubs for its static analysis, this means it is unaware that `complex` has this method. `complex.__float__` is likely omitted from the typeshed stub due to the fact that the method always raises `TypeError`; for this reason, [the `__float__` method has in fact been removed from the `complex` class in Python 3.10](https://docs.python.org/3.10/whatsnew/3.10.html#removed).
3. Any user-defined class, even if it is not a numeric class, could potentially define `__float__`. In fact, there are even several non-numeric classes in the standard library that define `__float__`. For example, although the `str` type in Python (which is written in C) does not have a `__float__` method, `collections.UserString` (which is written in pure Python) does. ([The source code for `str` is here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/c96d1546b11b4c282a7e21737cb1f5d16349656d/Objects/unicodeobject.c), and [the source code for `collections.UserString` is here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/0742abdc48886b74ed3b66985a54bb1c32802670/Lib/collections/__init__.py#L1315).)

---

**Example usage**

This passes MyPy for all numeric types I tested it with, except for `complex`:

```
from typing import SupportsFloat


NumberType = type[SupportsFloat]


def foo(bar: NumberType) -> None:
    pass
```

> *[Try it on MyPy playground here!](https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=latest&python=3.10&gist=5f9378d479cefcf7f422a48108b4406c&flags=show-error-codes%2Cstrict)*

If we want `complex` to be accepted as well, a naive tweak to this solution would just be to use the following snippet instead, special-casing `complex`. This satisfies MyPy for every numeric type I could think of. I've also thrown `type[Number]` into the type hint, as it *could* be useful to catch a hypothetical class that *does* directly inherit from `numbers.Number` and *does not* have a `__float__` method. I don't know why anybody would write such a class, but there are *some* classes that directly inherit from `numbers.Number` (e.g. [`fractions.Fraction`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/9626ac8b7421aa5fc04a30359521d24f40105141/Lib/fractions.py#L38)), and it certainly would be theoretically *possible* to create a direct subclass of `Number` without a `__float__` method. [`Number` itself is an empty class that has no methods](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/c379bc5ec9012cf66424ef3d80612cf13ec51006/Lib/numbers.py#L12) — it exists solely to provide a "virtual base class" for other numeric classes in the standard library.

```
from typing import SupportsFloat, Union 
from numbers import Number


NumberType = Union[type[SupportsFloat], type[complex], type[Number]]

# You can also write this more succinctly as:
# NumberType = type[Union[SupportsFloat, complex, Number]]
# The two are equivalent.

# In Python >= 3.10, we can even write it like this:
# NumberType = type[SupportsFloat | complex | Number]
# See PEP 604: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0604/


def foo(bar: NumberType) -> None:
    pass
```

> *[Try it on MyPy playground here!](https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=latest&python=3.10&gist=565b61c2b131c5449b5eeb28ab046a24&flags=show-error-codes%2Cstrict)*

Translated into English, `NumberType` here is equivalent to:

> Any class, if and only if:
>
> 1. It has a `__float__` method;
> 2. AND/OR it is `complex`;
> 3. AND/OR it is a subclass of `complex`;
> 4. AND/OR it is `numbers.Number`;
> 5. AND/OR it is a "strict" (non-virtual) subclass of `numbers.Number`.

I don't see this as a "solution" to the problem with `complex` — it's more of a workaround. The issue with `complex` is illustrative of the dangers of this approach in general. There may be other unusual numeric types in third-party libraries, for example, that do not directly subclass `numbers.Number` or have a `__float__` method. It would be exceedingly difficult to know what they might look like in advance, and special-case them all.

---

## Addenda

**Why `SupportsFloat` instead of [`typing.SupportsInt`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.SupportsInt)?**

`fractions.Fraction` has a `__float__` method ([inherited from `numbers.Rational`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/9626ac8b7421aa5fc04a30359521d24f40105141/Lib/numbers.py#L282-L283)) but does not have an `__int__` method.

**Why `SupportsFloat` instead of [`SupportsAbs`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.SupportsAbs)?**

Even `complex` has an `__abs__` method, so `typing.SupportsAbs` looks like a promising alternative at first glance! However, there are several other classes in the standard library that have an `__abs__` method and do not have a `__float__` method, and it would be a stretch to argue that they are all numeric classes. ([`datetime.timedelta`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/0742abdc48886b74ed3b66985a54bb1c32802670/Lib/datetime.py#L644) doesn't *feel* very number-like to me.) If you used `SupportsAbs` rather than `SupportsFloat`, you would risk casting your net too wide and allowing all sorts of non-numeric classes.

**Why `SupportsFloat` instead of [`SupportsRound`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.SupportsRound)?**

As an alternative to `SupportsFloat`, you could also consider using `typing.SupportsRound`, which accepts all classes that have a `__round__` method. This is just as comprehensive as `SupportsFloat` (it covers all major numeric types other than `complex`). It also has the  advantage that `collection.UserString` has no `__round__` method whereas, as discussed above, it does have a `__float__` method. Lastly, it seems less likely that third-party non-numeric classes would include a `__round__` method.

However, if you went for `SupportsRound` rather than `SupportsFloat`, you would, in my opinion, run a greater risk of excluding valid third-party numeric classes that, for whatever reason, do not define `__round__`.

"Having a `__float__` method" and "having a `__round__` method" are both pretty poor definitions of what it means for a class to be a "number". However, the former feels much *closer* to the "true" definition than the latter. As such, it feels *safer* to count on third-party numeric classes having a `__float__` method than it does to count on them having a `__round__` method.

If you wanted to be "extra safe" when it comes to ensuring a valid third-party numeric type is accepted by your function, I can't see any particular *harm* in extending `NumberType` even *further* with `SupportsRound`:

```
from typing import SupportsFloat, SupportsRound, Union
from numbers import Number

NumberType = Union[type[SupportsFloat], type[SupportsRound], type[complex], type[Number]]
```

However, I would question whether it's really *necessary* to include `SupportsRound`, given that any type that has a `__round__` method is very likely to have a `__float__` method as well.

---

<sup><sub>*...except for `complex`</sub></sup>

Comment: Nice! I suspect this very accurately covers what most people need as numbers!

Comment: I am slowly beginning to understand the root of the problem. Thanks for the in-depth explanation.

Comment: @s-m-e, pleasure :)

Comment: @s-m-e, you and dozens (maybe hundreds at this point) of other developers who have encountered these hidden crevasses. Without taking a dependency on aspirational future versions of Python, [this is the approach I used for ``dyce``](https://github.com/posita/dyce/blob/master/dyce/types.py) after [struggling for quite some time](https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/3186#issuecomment-885718629). It's a workaround that rebuilds/introduces various ``SupportsXYZ`` protocols that got me where I needed to go for 3.7+. I introduced a caching metaclass to mitigate `Protocol`'s performance problems.

Comment: BTW, many kudos to @AlexWaygood for unpacking this. As I [mentioned elsewhere](https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/3186#issuecomment-932828168), this is definitely a bounty-worthy response that shouldn't need to be written. But I'm grateful that it's here.

Comment: this is one of the most in-depth answers I’ve read on this site

Comment: Note that `np.ndarray` satisfies `SupportsFloat`, which may be unexpected to those who expect "numbers" to be scalars.

Comment: But am I correct that the advertised solution does still fail when you put a default argument of integer when it is type with `SupportFloat` https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=latest&python=3.10&gist=98b9ba3edd02db5023edccb9f0099208&flags=show-error-codes%2Cstrict

Answer (score 4):

There is no general way to do this. Numbers are not strictly related to begin with and their types are even less.

---

While `numbers.Number` might seem like "the type of numbers" it is not universal. For example, [`decimal.Decimal` is explicitly not a `numbers.Number`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3141/#the-decimal-type) as either subclass, subtype or virtual subclass. Specifically for typing, `numbers.Number` is [not endorsed by PEP 484 -- Type Hints](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/#the-numeric-tower).

In order to meaningfully type hint "numbers", one has to explicitly define what numbers are in that context. This might be a pre-existing numeric type set such as `int` <: `float` <: `complex`, a `typing.Union`/`TypeVar` of numeric types, a `typing.Protocol` to define operations and algebraic structure, or similar.

```py
from typing import TypeVar
from decimal import Decimal
from fractions import Fraction

#: typevar of rational numbers if we squint real hard
Q = TypeVar("Q", float, Decimal, Fraction)
```

---

All that said, "the type of the type of numbers" is even less meaningful. Even the *specific* `numbers.Number` has practically no features at all: it cannot be converted to a concrete type, nor can it be instantiated to a meaningful number.

Instead, use "the type of *some* type of numbers":

```py
from typing import Type

def zero(t: Type[Q]) -> Q:
    return t()  # all Type[Q]s can be instantiated without arguments

print(zero(Fraction))
```

If the only goal of the `Type` is to create instances, it can be better to request a `Callable` instead. This covers types as well as factory functions.

```py
def one(t: Callable[[int], Q]) -> Q:
    return t(1)
```

Comment: Bit of a nitpick — but `decimal.Decimal` is in fact registered as a virtual subclass of `numbers.Number` — it's just registered in the `decimal` module rather than the `numbers` module. The decision to add it as a virtual subclass must have been made some time after the publication of PEP 3141 :) `issubclass(Decimal, Number)` evaluates to `True`. https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/e9ce081ec7fe6f45059e1de93952ad53e9c3aa74/Lib/_pydecimal.py#L3846

Answer (score 3):

This is not ***quite*** an answer to the original question. ([Alex Waygood's answer](/a/69383462/3566894) is properly selected as responsive.) However, I have attempted to generalize my own work-arounds for the sharp edges between numbers and typing in Python. Those work-arounds now live in [`numerary`](https://github.com/posita/numerary/) (having extracted it via c-section from [`dyce`](https://github.com/posita/dyce/), where it was conceived).

I didn't spend a lot of time on naming, in the hopes it will be short-lived. [Docs are online.](https://posita.github.io/numerary/) It should be considered experimental, but it is rapidly approaching stability. [Feedback, suggestions, and contributions](https://posita.github.io/numerary/latest/contrib/) are desperately appreciated.

Comment: Amazing rant ... ehm ... library that you've built. Alex delivered the background, but this is clearly a ... solution. Thanks!