# How to type-hint / type-check a dictionary (at runtime) for an arbitrary number of arbitrary key/value pairs?

Tags: python, dictionary, type-hinting, python-typing

I am defining a class about as follows:

```py
from numbers import Number
from typing import Dict

from typeguard import typechecked

Data = Dict[str, Number]

@typechecked
class Foo:
    def __init__(self, data: Data):
        self._data = dict(data)
    @property
    def data(self) -> Data:
        return self._data
```

I am using `typeguard`. My intention is to restrict the types that can go into the data dictionary. Obviously, `typeguard` does check the entire dictionary if it is passed into a function or returned from one. If the dictionary is "exposed" directly, it becomes the dictionary's "responsibility" to check types - which does not work, obviously:

```py
bar = Foo({'x': 2, 'y': 3}) # ok

bar = Foo({'x': 2, 'y': 3, 'z': 'not allowed'}) # error as expected

bar.data['z'] = 'should also be not allowed but still is ...' # no error, but should cause one
```

[PEP 589](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0589/) introduces typed dictionaries, but for a fixed set of keys (similar to `struct`-like constructs in other languages). In contrast, I need this for a flexible number of arbitrary keys.

My best bad idea is to go "old-school": Sub-classing `dict` and re-implementing every bit of API through which data can go in (and out) of the dictionary and adding type checks to them:

```py
@typechecked
class TypedDict(dict): # just a sketch
    def __init__(
        self,
        other: Union[Data, None] = None,
        **kwargs: Number,
    ):
        pass # TODO
    def __setitem__(self, key: str, value: Number):
        pass # TODO
    # TODO
```

Is there a valid alternative that does not require the "old-school" approach?

Comment: "My best bad idea is to go "old-school": Sub-classing dict and re-implementing every bit of API through which data can go in (and out) of the dictionary and adding type checks to them" Don't do that. Use something like [collections.UserDict](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.UserDict)

Comment: In any case, I don't see any straightforward way for TypeGuard to accomplish this. Your `dict` is a regular Python `dict`, nothing you can do about it other than to provide y our own custom dict. Note, *static* analysis would catch this error, e.g., with `mypy`. EDIT: PEP 589 is irrelevant here. `TypeDict`'s are **simply for type hinting**, they return *regular dict's*.

Comment: You aren't actually asking about static type hinting, you are interested in runtime validation, it seems

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Yep, this is runtime checking. I adjusted the title. Hope it fits. Sub-classing `UserDict` instead of `dict`: Point taken, thanks. I am aware that PEP 589 is irrelevant, but I did not even know it existed before researching this question :) So I thought I might have overlooked something similar, closer to my needs.

Answer (score 6):

There seem to be several parts to your question.

##### (1) Creating a type-checked dictionary at runtime

[As @juanpa.arrivillaga says in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69555006/how-to-type-hint-type-check-a-dictionary-at-runtime-for-an-arbitrary-number#comment122963198_69555006), this has everything to do with type-*checking*, but doesn't seem to have anything to do with type-*hinting*. However, it's fairly trivial to design your own custom type-checked data structure. You can do it like this using [`collections.UserDict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.UserDict):

```
from collections import UserDict
from numbers import Number

class StrNumberDict(UserDict):
    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        if not isinstance(key, str):
            raise TypeError(
                f'Invalid type for dictionary key: '
                f'expected "str", got "{type(key).__name__}"'
            )
        if not isinstance(value, Number):
            raise TypeError(
                f'Invalid type for dictionary value: '
                f'expected "Number", got "{type(value).__name__}"'
            )
        super().__setitem__(key, value)
```

In usage:

```
>>> d = StrNumberDict()
>>> d['foo'] = 5
>>> d[5] = 6
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 5, in __setitem__
TypeError: Invalid type for dictionary key: expected "str", got "int"
>>> d['bar'] = 'foo'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 10, in __setitem__
TypeError: Invalid type for dictionary value: expected "Number", got "str"
```

If you wanted to generalise this kind of thing, you could do it like this:

```
from collections import UserDict

class TypeCheckedDict(UserDict):
    def __init__(self, key_type, value_type, initdict=None):
        self._key_type = key_type
        self._value_type = value_type
        super().__init__(initdict)

    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        if not isinstance(key, self._key_type):
            raise TypeError(
                f'Invalid type for dictionary key: '
                f'expected "{self._key_type.__name__}", '
                f'got "{type(key).__name__}"'
            )
        if not isinstance(value, self._value_type):
            raise TypeError(
                f'Invalid type for dictionary value: '
                f'expected "{self._value_type.__name__}", '
                f'got "{type(value).__name__}"'
            )
        super().__setitem__(key, value)
```

In usage:

```
>>> from numbers import Number
>>> d = TypeCheckedDict(key_type=str, value_type=Number, initdict={'baz': 3.14})
>>> d['baz']
3.14
>>> d[5] = 5
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 9, in __setitem__
TypeError: Invalid type for dictionary key: expected "str", got "int"
>>> d['foo'] = 'bar'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 15, in __setitem__
TypeError: Invalid type for dictionary value: expected "Number", got "str"
>>> d['foo'] = 5
>>> d['foo']
5
```

Note that you don't need to do type checks for the dictionary you pass to `super().__init__()`. `UserDict.__init__` calls `self.__setitem__`, which you've already overridden, so if you pass an invalid dictionary to `TypeCheckedDict.__init__`, you'll find an exception is raised in just the same way as if you try to add an invalid key or value to the dictionary after it has been constructed:

```
>>> from numbers import Number
>>> d = TypeCheckedDict(str, Number, {'foo': 'bar'})
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 5, in __init__
  line 985, in __init__
    self.update(dict)
  line 842, in update
    self[key] = other[key]
  File "<string>", line 16, in __setitem__
TypeError: Invalid type for dictionary value: expected "Number", got "str"
```

`UserDict` is specifically designed for easy subclassing in this way, which is why it is a better base class in this instance than `dict`.

If you wanted to add type hints to `TypeCheckedDict`, you'd do it like this:

```
from collections import UserDict
from collections.abc import Mapping, Hashable
from typing import TypeVar, Optional

K = TypeVar('K', bound=Hashable)
V = TypeVar('V')

class TypeCheckedDict(UserDict[K, V]):
    def __init__(
        self, 
        key_type: type[K], 
        value_type: type[V], 
        initdict: Optional[Mapping[K, V]] = None
    ) -> None:
        self._key_type = key_type
        self._value_type = value_type
        super().__init__(initdict)

    def __setitem__(self, key: K, value: V) -> None:
        if not isinstance(key, self._key_type):
            raise TypeError(
                f'Invalid type for dictionary key: '
                f'expected "{self._key_type.__name__}", '
                f'got "{type(key).__name__}"'
            )
        if not isinstance(value, self._value_type):
            raise TypeError(
                f'Invalid type for dictionary value: '
                f'expected "{self._value_type.__name__}", '
                f'got "{type(value).__name__}"'
            )
        super().__setitem__(key, value)
```

(The above [passes MyPy](https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=latest&python=3.10&flags=show-error-codes%2Cstrict&gist=6fe31c0ff1d341a56e34b6420a7ea6d0).)

Note, however, that adding type hints has no relevance at all to how this data structure works at runtime.

##### (2) Type-hinting dictionaries "for a flexible number of arbitrary keys"

I'm not quite sure what you mean by this, but if you want MyPy to raise an error if you add a string value to a dictionary you only want to have numeric values, [you could do it like this](https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=latest&python=3.10&gist=93a1fa01306e4d87df5b7a0f287037c2):

```
from typing import SupportsFloat

d: dict[str, SupportsFloat] = {}
d['a'] = 5  # passes MyPy 
d['b'] = 4.67 # passes MyPy
d[5] = 6 # fails MyPy
d['baz'] = 'foo' # fails Mypy
```

If you want MyPy static checks *and* runtime checks, your best bet (in my opinion) is to use the type-hinted version of `TypeCheckedDict` above:

```
d = TypeCheckedDict(str, SupportsFloat) # type: ignore[misc]
d['a'] = 5  # passes MyPy 
d['b'] = 4.67  # passes MyPy 
d[5] = 6  # fails Mypy 
d['baz'] = 'foo'  # fails Mypy
```

Mypy isn't too happy about us passing an abstract type in as a parameter to `TypeCheckedDict.__init__`, so you have to add a `# type: ignore[misc]` when instantiating the dict. (That feels like a MyPy bug to me.) Other than that, however, [it works fine](https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=latest&python=3.10&flags=show-error-codes%2Cstrict&gist=c7bffa7f03f6a6613c6198aa67100cf3).

(See my [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69334475/how-to-hint-at-number-types-i-e-subclasses-of-number-not-numbers-themselv/69383462#69383462) for caveats about using `SupportsFloat` to hint numeric types. Use `typing.Dict` instead of `dict` for type-hinting if you're on Python <= 3.8.)

##### (3) Using `typeguard`

Since you're using `typeguard`, you could simplify the logic in my `StrNumberDict` class a little, like so:

```
from collections import UserDict
from typeguard import typechecked
from typing import SupportsFloat

class StrNumberDict(UserDict[str, SupportsFloat]):
    @typechecked
    def __setitem__(self, key: str, value: SupportsFloat) -> None:
        super().__setitem__(key, value)
```

However, I don't think there's a way of doing this with `typeguard` if you want to have a more generic `TypeCheckedDict` that can be instantiated with arbitrary type-checking. The following ***does not*** work:

```
### THIS DOES NOT WORK ###

from typing import TypeVar, SupportsFloat
from collections.abc import Hashable
from collections import UserDict
from typeguard import typechecked

K = TypeVar('K', bound=Hashable)
V = TypeVar('V')

class TypeCheckedDict(UserDict[K, V]):
    @typechecked
    def __setitem__(self, key: K, value: V) -> None:
        super().__setitem__(key, value)

d = TypeCheckedDict[str, SupportsFloat]()
d[5] = 'foo'  # typeguard raises no error here.
```

It may also be worth noting that typeguard is [not currently maintained](https://github.com/agronholm/typeguard/issues/198), so there is a certain amount of risk involved in using that particular library.

Answer (score 1):

Good suggestions, but I observe that it gets much simpler than all that. @alex-waygood has some great explanations, and even if like me, you find his solution to be a tad overkill, his answer is much more correct.

```
class HomebrewTypeGuarding:
    """"Class mimics the primary interface of a dict, as an example
        of naive guarding using the __annotations__ collection that
        exists on any type-annotated object.
    """
    a: str
    b: int
    def __getitem__(self, key):
        return (
            self.__dict__[key] 
            if key in self.__dict__ 
            else None
        )
    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        if (
            key in self.__annotations__
            and isinstance(value, self.__annotations__[key])
        ):
            self.__dict__[key] = value
        else:
            raise ValueError(
                "Incorrect type for value on {}:{} = {}".format(
                    key,
                    str(
                        self.__annotations__[key] 
                        if key in self.__annotations__
                        else None
                    ),
                    str(value)
                )
            )
```

The plumbing here is much simpler, but do note I'm not claiming this is a dict. My intention is

1. To simply demonstrate type-guarding using the **annotations** collection, and
2. To do so in a way that can extend much further beyond dicts.

If you're really just after a type-checked dict, well, @alex-waygood goes into much greater detail there, and his solution is actually complete and correct.

If you are more interested in runtime-typechecking, at property or attribute assignment, I believe this solution is superior, simply because it can actually happen reliably, for many types, where the more correct and complete option is either A, going to be copy-pasted into all your use-case implementations, or B, converted into a metaclass or decorator that modifies the getitem and setitem dunders, to be some form of the below.

Note that, for B, many possible usecases that have different requirements. @s-m-e specified dict, and this doesn't directly work as a wrapper/decorator for a dict, but could be readily adapted. I would prefer that you invoke the original getitem/setitem dunders on a decorated class/instance for that, instead of directly mutating the `self.__dict__` or `self` collection. I was going for the simplest-possible example of using the annotations object to type-check. If write a class or instance decorator that installs (or overrides) a getitem/setitem pair, and if those dunders simply read/mutate `self.__dict__`, it breaks for dicts. If you observe this disclaimer, and write out the the `super().__getitem__(in_key)`, then there's the edge-case with first-generation classes (e.g., some implementations of such a decorator still fail) and with multiple-inheritance, for the usual issues with inheritance traversal. By the time you're solving that, you're almost definitely using getattrs on the type, and exploring multiple parallel paths for the `__getitem__` and `__setitem__` methods or properties that are relevant.