# Is there a way to do static typing in dicts?

Tags: python, python-typing

I would like to create a dictionary, but use static typing so I am certain the value assigned is the correct type, like you can do with variables or parameters. Is this possible?

Comment: Please update your question with the code you have tried.

Comment: You might want to look into tools like Pydantic (not sure it'll solve your problem but it's a good bet) or use OOP. Also, I suspect this is a bad question for SO.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.TypedDict? Or something else - are you looking for _runtime_ type checking, or ...? Strong typing is quite different to static typing, for example.

Comment: @quamrana This isn't a debugging question, and code has never been a requirement for a good question.

Comment: Anyways, this is either a dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44225788/python-3-dictionary-with-known-keys-typing (static type checker) or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69555006/how-to-type-hint-type-check-a-dictionary-at-runtime-for-an-arbitrary-number (runtime type checker), depending on which one OP wants.

Comment: There are several type validators in python, for simple use I would recommend  `TypedDict` as several comments pointed out. You can use Pydantic in bigger projects, for example building an API with `FastAPI`. There are other validators for other structures, but that's beyond the scope of your question.

Comment: `TypedDict` is the way to go if you want it to be a dict, but in most situations where I'd previously have used a `TypedDict` I'll now use a `dataclass` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can import TypedDict from typing and use it! See this sample:

```
from typing import TypedDict
class Movie(TypedDict):
  name: str
  rank: int
```

and now, python will accept something like this:

```
movie: Movie = { ‘name’: ‘God Father’, ‘rank’: 1 }
```

but if you give name, a value of int type, or give rank a value of double type for example, python type checking will give you error!

you can also refer to [this link](https://peps.python.org/pep-0589/) for more info.